# Schedule notification in android

Tags: android, notifications

i've a problem with a scheduling of notification, i don't receive anything, here mi cose:

**Class AlarmSet**:

```
public void AlarmStart() {
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
     cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
     cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, sender);
     Log.d("MyActivity", "Set alarmManager.setRepeating to: " + cal.getTime().toLocaleString());
}
```

**Class AlarmReceiver**:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent objIntent) {
    Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Called context.startService from AlarmReceiver.onReceive");
}
```

and in **manifest**:
...
...

```
receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">
/application>
```

I get first log message, so it seems to set the activity, then i don't receive anything else. The context is passed from another activity class, since these are simple class.

Any idea of what am i wrong? I've seen other user's code and it's pretty equal to mine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say why you are trying to set this up with a broadcast rather than using a service. What you can do (if your intention is just to schedule notifications) is to try changing the PendingIntent to start an IntentService instead of triggering a broadcast:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, sender                      );
```

Then, put your code to deal with the actual notification sending etc. in the onHandleIntent() method of YourService (which extends IntentService).

Comment: Isn't the broadcast receiver needed in case you want your notification to, say, survive reboots or the app being closed down?